# ibm-cos-sdk gets missing credentials in config issue

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, credentials, object-storage

I am using ibm-cos-sdk v1.1.4 to access IBM Cloud. But I got a very strange issue that missing credentials in config. I used codes like below to upload/download files from IBM Cloud. And these scripts are working in FVT environment. Only get such issues in PROD environment. Could someone help to tell me if there is anything wrong or how to fix it? Thanks.

FVT is using Nodejs v4.8.4 and PROD is using Nodejs v4.4.7. But I don't think that is root cause about Nodejs version since I have tested both v4.8.4 and v4.4.7 in FVT and the AWS.S3 was working.

```
var config = {
    endpoint: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    apiKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
    serviceInstanceId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
};

var cos = new AWS.S3(config);
console.log(cos.config.credentials); <=== I have checked the config.credentials and it's not empty.
cos.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        errorClbk(err);
    } else
        successClbk();
});
```

Below are error message:

```
[CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  time: Tue Apr 03 2018 04:06:39 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from Credentials',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     errno: 'ECONNRESET',
     syscall: 'read',
     time: Tue Apr 03 2018 04:06:39 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     originalError: 
      { message: 'Missing credentials in config',
        code: 'CredentialsError',
        errno: 'ECONNRESET',
        syscall: 'read',
        time: Tue Apr 03 2018 04:06:39 GMT+0000 (UTC),
        originalError: [Object] } }
```

Comment: Strange is that other than PROD environment is working, so - what needs to be checked are cerdentials, service instance id or permissions..

Comment: I think cerdentials should be good since scripts were working on local and FVT. I also tested on PROD that get object from cloud by using CURL and it worked. For now, I have no idea why nodejs cannot load credentials. That is so weird to me.

curl command:
curl "https://(endpoint)/(bucket-name)/(object-key)" -H "Authorization: bearer (token)"